# Detect first FOSFacebookBundle login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

I implemented successfully the FOSFacebookBundle with the FOSUserBundle. Everything works great.

Now, I'd like to be able to detect the first connection of an user with the FOSFacebookBundle.

I have a FacebookAuthenticationSuccessHandler which is called every time a Facebook authentication successes, but I'd like to declare a kind of "FirstFacebookAuthenticationSuccessHandler", called only if the user didn't exist yet. The goal of this handler is to be able to send a welcome email to each new user.

For the classic registration, I simply use a RegistrationSuccessListener.

Do you have any idea on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found the solution.

1/ I created (and registered) a new event listener called NewFacebookUserListener:

```
...

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
 public static function getSubscribedEvents()
 {
      return array(
          MyCustomEvents::NEW_FACEBOOK_USER => 'onNewFacebookUser'
      );
 }

 public function onNewFacebookUser(UserEvent $event)
 {
      // we get the user
      $user = $event->getUser();

      // and now you can do what you wish
 }
```

2/ In my FacebookProvider (located under Security/User/Provider), I added a few lines to dispatch this new event:

```
$user->setFBData($fbdata);

// we send a "FB user created" event
$dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
$dispatcher->dispatch(MyCustomEvents::NEW_FACEBOOK_USER, new UserEvent($user, $this->container->get('request')));
```

And as expected, the event is dispatched only when a new Facebook user is created.